# How do I add a "base URL" to all react-admin pages?

Tags: react-admin

I am trying to integrate react-admin into an existing react app and am able to get the basic starter pages up and running , however, after adding a dummy resource and clicking on it in the UI, I am redirected to `http://my-application.net/[resource name]`, which is incorrectly showing my applications error page.

I am trying to set up react admin in a sandbox-like scenario to avoid conflicts with some custom stuff I'm using for routing* and I currently have things set up to display react-admin under the `/admin` path in my app. **Is it possible to tell react-admin to prefix all of its links (i.e. when clicking on a resource) with `admin` so that my app can correctly detect and route these pages to react-admin?** For example, in the scenario from the last paragraph, when clicking on the dummy resource, i want it to direct me to `http://my-application.net/admin/[resource name]` instead of `http://my-application.net/[resource name]`

The closest I have been able to get is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50414523/react-admin-how-to-call-dataprovider-with-nested-path-like-abc-def/51847897#51847897) SO post, which talks about adding `admin/` as a prefix to the `name` of all resources. I have been able to make this work with some tweaks to my routing configuration to send all `/admin` pages to react-admin, but changing the resource names like this also has the side effect of changing them in the UI (i.e. my `users` resource appears as `admin/users` in the sidebar of react-admin)

Other things I looked at that didn't seem to be useful:

- [Using the `customRoutes`](https://marmelab.com/react-admin/Admin.html#customroutes) prop in `<Admin>`
- [`<Resource>`'s props](https://marmelab.com/react-admin/Resource.html#name) seem to be intended more for tweaking the end of urls for different CRUD operations
- [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67036427/in-react-admin-how-can-i-prefix-a-urlfield-href) SO post seems like it might be about something different since this is the first mention ive seen of `UrlField`.

Does React-admin have an option to automatically add a baseUrl to all it's links?

* While not relevant for this question, the reason I am trying to do things this way is because my routing system (UniversalRouter, see [here](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/an-introduction-to-the-redux-first-routing-model-98926ebf53cb/)) is redux-based and appears to directly conflict with some of the redux state that react-admin needs according to the [Using redux in a custom app](https://marmelab.com/react-admin/CustomApp.html) tutorial.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63288831) I found from a post the StackOverflow "related" sidebar seems to suggest that the history API has this kind of functionality:

> The only other thing I can think of is properly configuring baseName in your history.

referring to this line in the OP's question (variable name changed for clarity):

> `const newHistory = createHistory({ basename: '/myadmin' });`

Passing this modified history into react-admin's `Admin` component seems to achieve the intended behavior where clicking on resource links now correctly redirects to that resource underneath the specified baseURL.

> `<Admin ... history={newHistory} ...>`

This is also mentioned in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50497983) other answer, which is way more concise than mine or the one i based this answer off of.